# Comparing quantities of unique elements contained in large data sets

Tags: ios, regex, swift, hash, set

I'm attempting to solve [HackerRank's Hash Table Ransom Note](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note) challenge. There are 19 test cases and I'm passing all but two of time due to timeout on larger data sets (10,000-30,000 entries).

I'm given:

1) an array of words contained in a magazine and

2) an array of words for a ransom note. My objective is to determine if the words in the magazine can be used to construct a ransom note.

I need to have enough unique elements in the `magazineWords` to satisfy the quantity needed by `noteWords`.

I'm using this code to make that determination...and it takes FOREVER...

```
for word in noteWordsSet {
    // check if there are enough unique words in magazineWords to put in the note
    if magazineWords.filter({$0==word}).count < noteWords.filter({$0==word}).count {
        return "No"
    }
}
```

What is a faster way to accomplish this task?

Below is my complete code for the challenge:

```
import Foundation

var magazineWords = // Array of 1 to 30,000 strings
var noteWords = // Array of 1 to 30,000 strings

enum RegexString: String {
    // Letters a to z, A to Z, 1 to 5 characters long
    case wordCanBeUsed = "([a-zA-Z]{1,5})"
}

func matches(for regexString: String, in text: String) -> [String] {
    // Hat tip MartinR for this
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexString)
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}

func canCreateRansomNote(from magazineWords: [String], for noteWords: [String]) -> String {
    // figure out what's unique
    let magazineWordsSet = Set(magazineWords)
    let noteWordsSet = Set(noteWords)
    let intersectingValuesSet = magazineWordsSet.intersection(noteWordsSet)

    // constraints specified in challenge
    guard magazineWords.count >= 1, noteWords.count >= 1 else { return "No" }
    guard magazineWords.count <= 30000, noteWords.count <= 30000 else { return "No" }

    // make sure there are enough individual words to work with
    guard magazineWordsSet.count >= noteWordsSet.count else { return "No" }
    guard intersectingValuesSet.count == noteWordsSet.count else { return "No" }

    // check if all the words can be used. assume the regex method works perfectly
    guard noteWords.count == matches(for: RegexString.wordCanBeUsed.rawValue, in: noteWords.joined(separator: " ")).count else { return "No" }

    // FIXME: this is a processor hog. I'm timing out when I get to this point
    // need to make sure there are enough magazine words to write the note
    // compare quantity of word in magazine with quantity of word in note
    for word in noteWordsSet {
        // check if there are enough unique words in magazineWords to put in the note
        if magazineWords.filter({$0==word}).count < noteWords.filter({$0==word}).count {
            return "No"
        }
    }

    return "Yes"
}

print(canCreateRansomNote(from: magazineWords, for: noteWords))
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729865/refactored-solution-in-swift ...

Comment: Btw, in programming contests you usually don't have to *verify* the given constraints. You can take it for granted that your program is called with at most 30,000 words of maximal 5 letters.

Comment: @MartinR Brilliant! Thank you. Looking at it right now and it seems I was generally on the right path, but I could do a lot of cleanup w/ validation code. Once I figure it out, I'll update. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to read from the test case on the contest website or what frameworks you are allowed. If Foundation is allowed, you can use `NSCountedSet`

```
import Foundation

let fileContent = try! String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/file.txt"))
let scanner = Scanner(string: fileContent)

var m = 0
var n = 0
scanner.scanInt(&m)
scanner.scanInt(&n)

var magazineWords = NSCountedSet(capacity: m)
var ransomWords = NSCountedSet(capacity: n)

for i in 0..<(m+n) {
    var word: NSString? = nil
    scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: .whitespacesAndNewlines, into: &word)

    if i < m {
        magazineWords.add(word!)
    } else {
        ransomWords.add(word!)
    }
}

var canCreate = true
for w in ransomWords {
    if ransomWords.count(for: w) > magazineWords.count(for: w) {
        canCreate = false
        break
    }
}

print(canCreate ? "Yes" : "No")
```

It works by going through the input file one word at a time, counting how many times that word appears in the magazine and in the ransom note. Then if any word appear more frequently in the ransom note than in the magazine, it fails the test immediately. Run the 30,000 words test case in less than 1 second on my iMac 2012.

Comment: Thank you! I discovered `NSCountedSet` was the ticket home on this one. I got it working for most of the test cases, but 2 with large data sets were killing me. Thanks for reading.